# Get a list of the street names within a distance of an input point. Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, qgis

I have a table imported into PGadmin(4) my rows of data are only the ID, the Geometry and bin_no. I want to write a code on how to get the street names from within a certain distance, let's say the input point would be -74.01037795652,40.7036359134451.  How do I go about this?

Please be kind I am new to this and am currently working on a class homework assignment.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You asked a mouth full here.  PostGIS is the geo-enabled Postgres, so first step is to get that installed.  Second step would to be get a list of streets...streets are generally line segments, so you'll have a table that is 'streetname' and the a geometry representation of that street.  Then you will be ready for the fun code...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42003/how-to-find-nearest-line-from-point-using-postgis     gis is it's own forum here on stack, it's complicated and not the best place to begin with in SQL.